# Not linking the CSS file from the JSP in Cross Domain request in IE9

Tags: html, css, jsp, gwt

I have build GWTP web application and i am calling the JSP page on different domain (Cross domain) from my GWT client side in AJAX call.

Some times the CSS files are linking correctly and working fine, but few times in not linking.

The Issue will be browser or cross side implementation in my code ?

Any body can help this above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some time your async call takes too long and your css is injected after document ready - due to lack of information / code i'm not able to proof it, though.

Try to load css with a callback and parse the rest of your document once the css has been injected successfully.

Comment: Sorry for late reply....i am using the **XDomainRequest** object for calling the cross domain request. So there **how can i define the callback function.** and also if i define the callback, then my application performance will get slow ? bcoz the application will wait for the callback response.